# Maximum Entropy modelling - likelihood equation

Tags: machine-learning, probability, natural-language, likelihood, maximum-entropy

I am trying to understand maximum entropy modelling and I came across log likelihood equation of the empirical distribution, which I did not quite understand, which also eventually turns out to be equal to the dual function we get when trying to maximise the entropy with constraints using Lagrange's multipliers

$$ L_\widetilde{p}(p) \equiv log \prod\limits_{x,y}p(y|x)^{\widetilde{p}(x,y)} = \sum\limits_{x,y}\widetilde{p}(x,y)\log{p(y|x)}$$

Where,

- $y$ is the outcome produced by a random process
- $x$ is the feature influencing the outcome $y$
- $L_\widetilde{p}(p)$ is the log likelihood
- $\widetilde{p}$ is the empirical distribution of training data
- $p(y|x)$ is the model
- $\widetilde{p}(x,y) \equiv \frac{1}{N} \times \text{number of times that } (x,y) \text{ occurs in the sample} $

Can someone please explain how $p(y|x)$ is raised to the power of $\widetilde{p}(x,y)$ in the log likelihood equation mentioned above? Instead, shouldn't $p(x|y)$ be raised to the power of number of times that $(x,y)$ occurs in the sample.

I went through this [reference tutorial on max entropy](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs/user/aberger/www/html/tutorial/node8.html).

Answer (score 1):

As you have already said, if $\tilde p$ is the empirical distribution of the data then by definition $\tilde p(x,y)=\frac{n(x,y)}{N}$ where $N$ is the total sample size and $n(x,y)$ is the number of times $(x,y)$ occurs in the sample. Thus :

$$\log\prod p(x,y)^{\tilde p(x,y)}=\log\left(\prod p(x,y)^{n(x,y)}\right)^{1/N}=\frac{1}{N}\log\prod p(x,y)^{n(x,y)}$$

The quantity on the left is thus proportional to the log likelihood. Since the main goal is maximizing it, the proportionality constant can be skipped. I guess the authors mistakenly call it "log likelihood" which is a minor misnomer.

This quantity is the **average log likelihood per observation**, that is easier to use because somehow independent of the sample size and easier to compare across datasets of different sizes. Personally I always work with this quantity for this reason and also call it "log likelihood" informally.